# Drupal 8: Unwanted N/A option showing in radio button

Tags: drupal-8

I'm using Drupal 8. How to remove N/A option in radio button?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 6):

n/a option doesn't shows up if your field is required.

Assuming you don't want to make it required, here are the steps to remove this option.

Firstly, you need to add a process function for the radio buttons (you must create a module and insert this code in it)

```
function yourmodule_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['radios'])) {
    $types['radios']['#process'][] = 'remove_radio_na';
  }
}
```

Then create the process function. Let say that you have several boolean fields and you would like to remove the n/a option only for the field "field_bool_no_na"

```
function remove_radio_na($element) {
  if ($element['#field_name']=='field_bool_no_na') {
    unset($element['_none']);
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function MODULENAME_options_list_alter(array &$options, array $context) {
     unset($options['_none']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a CSS solution, you can hide the 1st child of the .form-radios item like this:

```
.form-radios > .form-item:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

(as long as you don't have any required Booleans.)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be using hook_form_alter
After adding bellowed code on your hook_form_alter "N/A" removed from Radio Buttons.

Sample code for removing n/a in user profile custom radio button field:

```
function your_module_name_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id, 'user_form') !== FALSE) {
    unset($form['your_field_name']['widget']['#options']['_none']);
  }
}
```